# What may be preventing iOS 15 rich web search results from being shown in Spotlight?

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, spotlight, siri

After upgrading to iOS 15 on my iPhone 12 mini, I was expecting to see rich results from the web in Spotlight, as in this example from an [AppleInsider article](https://appleinsider.com/articles/21/08/09/how-to-use-the-new-spotlight-in-ios-15):

[image: Example of iOS 15 Spotlight rich web results]

However, when I search for something that I’m sure should trigger such new rich results (like the full name of a president or a celebrity, including the “William Gallagher” query from the above example), I get nothing:

[image: Screenshot from iOS 15 with rich web results missing]

I have the *Content From Apple* settings enabled for Spotlight in the *Siri & Search* settings, to no avail:

[image: Screenshot of Siri & Search settings]

Since I have Siri, the voice assistant per se, turned off, as you can see in the above screenshot, I tried turning it on, full mode, with voice activation:

[image: Screenshot of Siri & Search settings with Siri voice activation enabled]

That has not helped (even after a reboot).

I have also made sure that I have all Siri-related settings turned on for Safari:

[image: Screenshot of Siri settings for Safari]

My iPhone configuration is not really unusual or esoteric in other respects by any means, either.

It doesn’t seem to be a complete failure of rich results, too, as I get those from the Contacts app, for example. It is only the rich *web search* results that are missing for some reason.

Hence I cannot help but wonder:

**What might be preventing rich *web* results from being shown in Spotlight?**

Are there any settings affecting this feature? Is it a known bug?

Comment: Just wanted to let you know, you are not alone. I'm having the same experience. I contacted Apple Support, they put me in contact with an expert engineer, or something like that, and they couldn't figure out what was going on, so they ended up concluding that it might be due to a bug that could be fixed in a minor version upgrade

Comment: @NickLScott: Thank you for letting me (and others who suffer from the same issue and might find this question via search) know! I hope it is indeed a bug that will be fixed in the next minor release. If it will be fixed, I will update this question accordingly. If you happen to hear any news on that or stumble upon a solution, please share it here, too!

Comment: Ik it wont be of help, but I’m seeing the same. iOS 15 11 pro max.